# Laravel 5.4 View could not see method From Controller

Tags: laravel

I have redo Function which is used for re-doing test/quiz again, so in order to do that I have test_result table, so I am trying to delete particular test_result item from database but my view page could not see Controller Method

My View Page

```
{!!Form::open(['action' => ['LessonsController@testredo', $test_result->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'float-right'])!!} 
{{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}} 
    {{Form::submit('Redo Test', ['class' => 'btn btn-info'])}} 
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

My Controller

```
class LessonsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function testredo($id)
    {
        $test_result = TestsResult::find($id);
        $test_result->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Re-Do test Good Luck!');
    }

}
```

Error Screenshot
[image]

Comment: I've found solution in routing it should be delete not post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the namespace of your `LessonsController` is `App\Http\Controllers` as below:

`namespace App\Http\Controllers`

One more thing;

If you have created this `LessonsController.php` file manually then you need to run the following command while you are in the root directory of the project:

`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I have checked namespace, and tried autoload, not helped to me(